# HTML class vs. id for a group of divs

Tags: html

This becomes confusing to me:

```
<div class='wrapper'>
   <div id='redRose' class='roses'>...</div>
</div>

 <div class='wrapper'>
   <div id='redRose' class='roses'>...</div>
</div>

 <div class='wrapper'>
   <div id='redRose' class='roses'>...</div>
</div>
```

I can see the obvious difference between 'redRose' and 'roses', but why he assigns the same id 'redRose' to multiple divs? It seems it looses id's unique identification character here. Did I miss something?

**Update:**

Thanks for everyone's help. I wish I could mark everyone's answer correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, the obvious thing to say is that markup is wrong.
Id is unique, class is not.

http://css-tricks.com/the-difference-between-id-and-class/

There could be an id of redRose to a parent container if one were to want to target something like `#redRose div` or `#redRose .roses` but as it stands the css for this would only target one of the id's specified and is just wrong to begin with.

Comment: I just took a closer look, each div id is wrapped around another div. I edited the original question. is it legal this way?

Comment: Sorry, commented on the wrong answer, but still same applies. Each id can only be used once on the page. They can be redRose1, redRose2, etc, but there may not be a point to doing so. Is there a reason why you want to assign a common id to these items?

Comment: No it was someone else's code I am trying to understand. He confused the heck out of me... :)

Comment: well, it's not confusing at all - he didn't know what he was doing.

Answer (score 3):

This is not valid; the id must be unique. Class names can be shared however.

http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/global.html#h-7.5.2

Comment: I just took a closer look, each div id is wrapped around another div. I edited the original question.

Comment: regardless of where the elements occur in the document, the id of each must be unique

Comment: I am not aware of a built-in error checking to throw a warning if same id is assigned to multiple elements, are you'

Answer (score 1):

Using the same ID more than once on any given page is wrong. It should never be done and will break code that references that ID. The proper way to do it is with classes. A css class can be assigned multiple times, whereas a ID can only be assigned once.

Comment: I just took a closer look, each div id is wrapped around another div. I edited the original question. is it legal this way?

Comment: nope. remember, there can only be one redRose id for each page. whole dom inclusive. It's primarily used for things like #header and such where there is typically only one.

Answer (score 0):

http://css-tricks.com/the-difference-between-id-and-class/

> **ID's are unique**
>   Each element can have only one ID Each page can have only one element
>   with that ID
>
> **Classes are NOT unique** You can use the same class on multiple
>   elements. You can use multiple classes on the same element.